# Can mobile devices take a global IPv6 address by means of only routing?

Tags: routing, ip, ipv6, ip-address, mobile

I'm probably asking this the wrong way, but here it is; I have a /48 block with static addresses for every device on the network. Everything is routed, no NAT, no tricks.

My question is: on a mobile device like a cellphone or tablet, what if I wanted to keep my internal--which is actually a global--address outside the bounds of my upstream router?

Without tunneling, is there a way to dynamically recreate routes after each cell/wirelessAP attached to a network to which my device comes in contact?

I'd love to check for myself but both of the carriers I have service with lack IPv6 support, so I *do* tunnel in.

Comment: Not likely. It'd require BGP advertising your own AS (/48 is the minimum size). I don't think any ISP allows BGP on mobile.

Comment: @Zac67, we have some mobile (4G) connections for backup at some sites, and the carriers allow us to use BGP. There are some strange restrictions, like requiring a `/64` IPv6 network for every point-to-point link between our "mobile" routers and the ISP routers. Apparently, that requirement is because of some standard that the mobile providers have created. They originally told us that we should use `/126` for the point-to-point links, but this standard popped up, and we had to change that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The ISPs will not route any IPv6 prefix longer than `/48`, and certainly not a `/128` address for a single device, but there is [Mobile IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6275) that automatically builds a tunnel back to the "home" network agent. You will need a router on your network that supports Mobile IPv6 to be the Home Agent for any mobile devices.

There are sources that explain Mobile IP at a high level, including the [Wikipedia Mobile IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_IP) article. If you search for `rfc mobile ipv6`, you will see many RFCs for various aspects of IPv6 mobility:

- [*RFC 3775, Mobility Support in IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3775)
- [*RFC 3776, Using IPsec to Protect Mobile IPv6 Signaling Between
  Mobile Nodes and Home Agents*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3776)
- [*RFC 4068, Fast Handovers for Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4068)
- [*RFC 4283, Mobile Node Identifier Option for Mobile IPv6
  (MIPv6)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4283)
- [*RFC 4285, Authentication Protocol for Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4285)
- [*RFC 4449, Securing Mobile IPv6 Route Optimization Using a Static
  Shared Key*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4449)
- [*RFC 4882, IP Address Location Privacy and Mobile IPv6: Problem
  Statement*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4882)
- [*RFC 5148, Service Selection for Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5149)
- [*RFC 5213, Proxy Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5213)
- [*RFC 5555, Mobile IPv6 Support for Dual Stack Hosts and
  Routers*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5555)
- [*RFC 5949, Fast Handovers for Proxy Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5949)
- [*RFC 6275, Mobility Support in IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6275)
- [*RFC 6463, Runtime Local Mobility Anchor (LMA) Assignment Support
  for Proxy Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6463)
- [*RFC 6475, Proxy Mobile IPv6 Management Information Base*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6475)
- [*RFC 6602, Bulk Binding Update Support for Proxy Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6602)
- [*RFC 6610, DHCP Options for Home Information Discovery in Mobile
  IPv6 (MIPv6)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6610)
- [*RFC 6611, Mobile IPv6 (MIPv6) Bootstrapping for the Integrated
  Scenario*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6611)
- [*RFC 6612, Interactions between Proxy Mobile IPv6 (PMIPv6) and
  Mobile IPv6 (MIPv6): Scenarios and Related Issues*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6612)
- [*RFC 6757, Access Network Identifier (ANI) Option for Proxy Mobile
  IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6757)
- [*RFC 6909, IPv4 Traffic Offload Selector Option for Proxy Mobile
  IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6909)
- [*RFC 7077, Update Notifications for Proxy Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7077)
- [*RFC 7028, Multicast Mobility Routing Optimizations for Proxy Mobile
  IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7028)
- [*RFC 7109, Flow Bindings Initiated by Home Agents for Mobile
  IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7109)
- [*RFC 7148, Prefix Delegation Support for Proxy Mobile IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7148)
- [*RFC 7156, Diameter Support for Proxy Mobile IPv6 Localized
  Routing*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7156)
- [*RFC 7389, Separation of Control and User Plane for Proxy Mobile
  IPv6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7389)
- [*RFC 7864, Proxy Mobile IPv6 Extensions to Support Flow
  Mobility*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7864)

Comment: Mobile IPv6 is definitely the way to go, but operating system support is very limited right now, surprisingly. There's some stuff you can hack together on Linux. Supposedly mobile IPv6 has existed in Windows forever, but good luck finding anything about actually setting it up. AFAIK Android and iOS have nothing either. This is unfortunate as it solves a lot of problems, or would if we had usable host implementations.